# Making list-group full-width - hortizontal scrollbar appears

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to make my `list-group` full container width with multiple columns (Bootstrap 3.2.0). I've created the following code:

```
<div class="container" style="background: red;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="list-group">   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <a href="" class="list-group-item">item1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">item2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">item3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">item4</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">item5</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">item6</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">item7</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<p class="row alert alert-warning text-center">
 message here
</p>
</div>
```

[Demo on Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/MjdMj6KiJQ)

The only problem here is that when you resize your browser window, for smaller resolution (probably sm) the horizontal scrollbar appears probably because of right margin or right padding. It seems it's probably connected to using `row` here.

When I remove the outer `.row` div there is no problem (no horizontal scrollbar appears - [Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/gUWqqLCNvd)) but in this case `list-group` won't take full container width.

Question - is it possible to solve it in simple way? Why does it happen? I know it's maybe not very standard solution (I put many extra divs inside `list-group`) but if possible I would like to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you are missing a `col-*` class. Bootstrap requires that nested rows need columns inside them as the immediate child but your hierarchy goes `container` -> `row` -> `row` -> `col-*`. So you just need to insert a `col-xs-12` in the middle, or more simply, add that class to your `list-group` div.

```
<div class="container" style="background: red;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 list-group">   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <a href="" class="list-group-item">item1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">item2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">item3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">item4</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">item5</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">item6</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">item7</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<p class="row alert alert-warning text-center">
 message here
</p>
</div>
```

And the Bootply is here: http://www.bootply.com/jIW90o3ZCA

Comment: This isn't true all the way you still have some padding right on the col-xs-12 ... The left value is override by the list-group but the right is still there

Comment: But unfortunately in your solution it also doesn't fill the full container width. You get right padding (red colour on right) in all resolutions

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any spacing between the list-group-items, then you'd need to add the list-group-item class to the columns:

```
<div class="container" style="background: red;">  
  <div class="row list-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 list-group-item">
      <a href="">item1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 list-group-item">
      <a href="">item1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 list-group-item">
      <a href="">item1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 list-group-item">
      <a href="">item1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 list-group-item">
      <a href="">item1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 list-group-item">
      <a href="">item1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 list-group-item">
      <a href="">item1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I know but I do want spacing between items exactly as in my code. The only problem here is scrollbar